# running windows powershell command in java

Tags: java, powershell

I am able to run this command in Windows PowerShell.

```
Add-Content -Path C:/Users/User/Desktop/sda.txt -Value "`nThis is the last line"
```

I tried to run the similar command via Java but it's not executing the command.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("powershell Add-Content -Path C:/Users/User/Desktop/sda.txt -Value " + "\"`nThis is the last line\"");
runtime.exec("powershell Add-Content -Path C:/Users/User/Desktop/sda.txt -Value " + "\"`nThis is the last line\"");
```

---

Second attempt as suggested by aquaraga

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc;
System.out.println("powershell Add-Content -Path C:/Users/User/Desktop/sda.txt -Value " + "\"`nThis is the last line\"");
proc = runtime.exec("powershell Add-Content -Path C:/Users/User/Desktop/sda.txt -Value " + "\"`nThis is the last line\"");
try {
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You have to assign the return value of runtime.exec to a variable, say proc. Then perform proc.waitFor()

Comment: It is most likely waiting for a user input or erroring out. Before you waitFor(), can you print the content of the process' error stream? You can refer to this gist: https://gist.github.com/aquaraga/758c09eb482d1934b4bb

Comment: Add-Content simply adds a line to the end of a file; why not program that functionality entirely in Java? It would be shorter & cleaner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the powershell command argument in a single quote:

```
proc = runtime.exec("powershell Add-Content -Path C:/Users/User/Desktop/sda.txt -Value " + "\"'`nThis is the last line'\"");
```